# How to create a 2d array to exclude certain directories from the program

Tags: python

I am new to python and I need a quick help with the below problem. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

I have a python script which purges logs from a directory called `XYZ`. The directory `XYZ` has sub directories for different applications and then the logs in it. e.g: `/XYZ/host1/syslog.log`
At present the python script takes the purge date with the `-p` option provided to it at the time to execution.

I want to change the purge date for one specific directory under `XYZ`, without changing the location of the directory.
Someone told me this can be done with creating an exception `2d array` to provide a host with `# of days` and in case a host is not present in that array then purge days is taken from the `-p` option.

Can someone please help me with creating this array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way that I can think of is inherit from dict:

```
class PurgeTimes(dict):
    def __missing__(self,key):
        return default_purge_time  #somehow created with -p commandline option
```

Then you can add directories to be purged at different (non-default) times:

```
purge_times=PurgeTimes()
#If you perfer, you could also use a `defaultdict` to do the same thing
#without subclassing.
#purge_times=collections.defaultdict(lambda : default_purge_time)

purge_times[dir1]=time1
purge_times[dir2]=time2
```

And finally loop through your directories and purge

```
for d in directories:
    if get_dir_time(d) < purge_time[d]:
       purge(d)
```

**PLEASE TEST THIS BEFORE PUTTING INTO PRODUCTION **  ;^)

Comment: This doesn't create a 2D array exactly -- But I don't understand what that has to do with the problem in the first place...

Comment: Hello mgilson, thanks for a quick solution.
I think it should work for me, I was looking for something like this itself, wherein I can specify directories with purge days and if not available for any then take default provided with -p option.

I'll test it in my environment and let you know.

Thanks again!

Comment: @mgilson, use `collections.defaultdict` instead of your hand-rolled substitute. `purge_times = defaultdict(lambda : default_purge_time)`

Comment: @alexis -- I agree a `defaultdict` could be used here, but I think this solution is a little more easy to understand and will work with python 2.4 AFAIK.  It's 1 extra line of code (2 extra if you have to `import collections` anyway), but it avoids the lambda which doesn't do much other than make it so `defaultdict` is happy that it's getting a callable object.  I'd also **guess** that my solution would be slightly more efficient since it avoids a function call each time (although I haven't timed it).

Comment: I suggested `defaultdict` precisely because it's documented and transparently named. I agree it's confusing that it requires `lambda`, but your solution extends a class, uses a magic method, and re-implements a function from the standard library. Anyway it's your code. (And I learned something: I didn't know the `__missing__` method :-))